# SwiftUI ScrollView is always without ResponsiveScrolling

Tags: xcode, macos, swiftui, macos-big-sur

When using an `ScrollView { ... }` in SwiftUI 2.0 in macOS Big Sur (or prior) the scroll runs fine but it is slower than NSScrollView in Cocoa. The same behaviour occurs in Cocoa when isResponsiveScrolling is set to false:

```
override class var isCompatibleWithResponsiveScrolling: Bool { return false }
```

When using a `List { ... }` in SwiftUI the scroll **is** **responsive**.

More info: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKitOlderNotes/#10_9Scrolling

Is there any way to get the `ScrollView` in SwiftUI with responsive behavior?

---

`Xcode 12 beta 4`  |  `macOS Big Sur beta 4`  |  `SwiftUI 2.0`

Comment: Most probably it is because SwiftUI ScrollView is transparent by default and not clipped (List is opaque).

Comment: It has sense. I tried accesing to NSScrollView background to make it opaque via introspectScrollView { _ in } but it doesn't work... :/